# CSS Issues with lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a small lightbox for playing youtube videos.
It works fine, but the design it's terrible.
Check it out.
[image]

I have try to fix it, but that's the best result I got.
A link of a JSbin where you can observe the lightbox. 
http://jsbin.com/UDIGeveg/1/edit

This is my CSS.
Not quite sure, what else I can do so the X of close appears fine in the dialog.

```
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: What are you asking us to do? Good design is different for everyone...

Comment: I want to know how to make the X of close appear completely in the dialog.

Comment: Well it looks like you gotta play with the right and top values in the css... Not knowing the rest of your css, it's hard to tell. Try -22px for right and -20px for top, see if that moves the 'X' button

Comment: That's why I include a JSbin. http://jsbin.com/UDIGeveg/1/edit I have try, but get bad results

Comment: On your `div#openMContainter` you need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` so it doesn't cut the close button off.

Comment: No problem, I added an answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from,

```
div#openMContainter { 
    width: 600px; 
    height: auto;
    display:block; 
}
```

The `overflow` is causing the button to only show what is visible inside of the parent.

Comment: Thanks. Still wondering why is a -1 question.

Comment: No problem, I'm sure someone may be grumpy or they felt the answer was obvious. I could see why they downvoted I guess since `overflow` is a common css style but who knows. Regardless, best of luck in your design.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are thinking, but my suggestion to tidy this would be:

Change the css to:

```
// Uniform padding around the screen, keeps the grey area constant
.modalDialog > div {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

//Moving the x 'close button'
//Amend the padding that determines the button position 
.close {
top: 2px;
right: 2px;
}
```

Then in the java:

```
// amend the width of the screen so that it fits into the grey area
width: '600',
```

Not sure if this is what you want but i would start with this to tidy up you end result.
Hope it helps.

Dan